# GCE Persistent Disk Same zone as Kubernetes Pod?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to mount a GCE persistent disk in a kubernetes pod via the deployment object yaml. 
I am observing this behavior that as long as the node (on which the pod resides) is in the same zone as the persistent disk (say us-central1-a), the mounting succeeds. 
However, if there are in different zones (say node in us-central1-a and disk in us-central1-b) then mounting times out.

Is this behavior valid? I could not find anything in the documentation that verifies that it is.

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/volumes/#gcePersistentDisk

We are using multi-zone clusters which is making it cumbersome to load the right disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCE Persistent Disks are a [zonal resource](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#introduction), so the pod can only request a PD that is in its zone.

Comment: The docs aren't that direct about the zonal thing. The best quote I found was "Unlike persistent disks, Cloud Storage buckets are not restricted to the zone where your instance is located."

Answer (score 3):

You can use this nodeSelector:

```
    nodeSelector:
      failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone: us-central1-b
```

Comment: Where do you add this attribute?

Comment: nodeSelector is part of the template spec.  I can't do formatting in this comment so I can't give you a detailed example, but `spec.template.spec.nodeSelector` is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

you need to schedule your pods on the same PD zone. In order to do that you need to use nodeSelector or nodeAffinity:required.

If you are using dynamically provisioned volumes, this needs to be topology aware. This is accomplished by setting the volumeBindingMode for the storage class to WaitForFirstConsumer: [volume binding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#volume-binding-mode)